# Find the minimum distance from the origin to the intersection of $xy=6$ with $7x+24z=0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find the minimum distance from the origin to the intersection of $xy=6$ with $7x+24z=0$.

> Solution:

We should minimize $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ subject to the two conditions  $g(x,y,z)=xy-6$ and    $h(x,y,z)=7x+24z-0$.
By the Lagranage multiplier method we , we have:$$\triangledown f=\lambda\triangledown  g+ \mu\triangledown  h \implies 2x \hat{i}+2y\hat{j}+2z\hat{k}=\lambda(7\hat{i}+24\hat{k})+\mu(y\hat{i}+x\hat{j})$$
From here, we have $$\begin{align*}2x=7\lambda+\mu y, \;\;2y=\mu x,\;\;2z=24\lambda \end{align*}$$

Now, we should solve these equations with $xy=6$ and $7x+24z=0$. How should I proceed  to solve for $x,y,z$ and $\mu,\lambda$. Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem? You have five equations in five unknowns. You should be able to solve them by eliminating variables between them. I'd suggest you eliminate $\lambda$ first and then $\mu$ since you don't care about their values. That should leave you three equations for the three unknowns you *do* care about. BTW, in the implication on the fifth line, you have switched the roles of $\lambda$ and $\mu$, although that does not make much difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number the equations:
$$2x=7\lambda+\mu y\tag1$$
$$2y=\mu x\tag2$$
$$2z=24\lambda\tag3$$
$$xy=6\tag4$$
$$7x+24z=0\tag5$$
We solve them as follows:

- From $(2)$ and $(4)$ we get $(6):12=\mu x^2$.
- From $(1)$ and $(4)$ we get $(7):2x=7\lambda+6\frac\mu x$.
- From $(7)$ and $(6)$ we get $(8):2x=7\lambda+\frac{72}{x^3}$.
- From $(8)$ and $(3)$ we get $(9):2x=\frac7{12}z+\frac{72}{x^3}$.
- From $(9)$ and $(5)$ we get $(10):2x=-\frac{49}{288}x+\frac{72}{x^3}$, or
  $$\frac{625}{288}x=\frac{72}{x^3}$$
  $$x^4=\frac{20736}{625}\implies x=\pm\frac{12}5$$
  From relations $(2)$ to $(5)$, we see that we will get symmetric solutions for the remaining variables upon changing the sign of $x$. The points where the intersection curve comes closest to the origin are
  $$(x,y,z)=\left(\pm\frac{12}5,\pm\frac52,\mp\frac7{10}\right)$$
  and the minimum distance is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\frac5{\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Lagrange multipliers, the intersection of the two sets consists of the points $\left(x,\frac{6}{x},-\frac{7x}{24}\right), x\ne 0$,
so we have to minimize
$$f(x)=x^2+\frac{36}{x^2}+\frac{49x^2}{576}=\frac{625x^4+20736}{576x^2} \\
f'(x)=\frac{625x^4-20736}{288x^3}$$
Setting $f'$ to $0$ and examining its sign, we find the minimum of $f$ is obtained when $x=\pm2.4$ and so the shortest distance is
$$\sqrt{f(\pm 2.4)}=\sqrt{\frac{25}{2}}=\frac{5}{\sqrt 2} $$